# Aligning of elements on my page is acting weird

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am trying to set out my webpage and I am facing a big problem. I have wrapped all of my code in a  tag as I wish to wrap all of my content in an additional background of different color.

However when I set the attributes for my code this happens:

[image]

It is as if by bottom element is overlapping somehow with the two above. I am using column separators I do not know if this affects it. Here is my full CSS & HTML code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
<script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="pull-left">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Featured</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="pull-right">
            <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
            <div id="logo-game">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/he/b/b7/Gamespot_logo.png">
</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="feature-cont">
            <div id="feature-cont-back">
        <h1>100's Of Featured Game Reviews</h1>
        <p>Browse through our collection of the most popular game reviews out there</p>
        <a href="#">Find Out More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bodytwo">
<!--Recommened Section-->
<div class="recommended">
<div class="text-center">
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="https://img.game.co.uk/merch/homeEspots/FranchiseLogos/FranchiseLogos_Destiny.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="https://img.game.co.uk/merch/homeEspots/FranchiseLogos/FranchiseLogos_CODAW.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="https://img.game.co.uk/merch/homeEspots/FranchiseLogos/FranchiseLogos_Evolve.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="https://img.game.co.uk/merch/homeEspots/FranchiseLogos/FranchiseLogos_AssassinsCreed.jpg"</li>
        <li><img src="https://img.game.co.uk/merch/homeEspots/FranchiseLogos/FranchiseLogos_FIFA.jpg"</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><img src="https://img.game.co.uk/merch/homeEspots/FranchiseLogos/FranchiseLogos_Forza.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="https://img.game.co.uk/merch/homeEspots/FranchiseLogos/FranchiseLogos_BattlefieldHardlines.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="https://img.game.co.uk/merch/homeEspots/FranchiseLogos/FranchiseLogos_GTAV.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="https://img.game.co.uk/merch/homeEspots/FranchiseLogos/FranchiseLogos_Halo.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="https://img.game.co.uk/merch/homeEspots/FranchiseLogos/FranchiseLogos_FarCry4.jpg">    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--Start Of Tables-->
<div class="mainc">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="new-game">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Games</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://static.gamespot.com/uploads/original/1197/11970954/2396871-battlefield4.jpeg">
            <p>Battlefield 4 is the genre-defining action blockbuster made from moments that blur the line between game and glory...</p>
        </td>
        <td>
                <img src="http://images.pushsquare.com/games/ps3/fifa_14/cover_large.jpg">
                <p>This year it's all about the emotion of scoring great goals - the challenge of building play as a team...</p>
        </td>    
        <td>
            <img src="http://images.pushsquare.com/games/ps3/dead_island_riptide/cover_large.jpg">
            <p>Take on hundreds of Zombies at once as your screen becomes swamped with the undead all after one thing…. You!</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="400">
               <img src="http://images.pushsquare.com/games/ps4/need_for_speed_rivals/cover_large.jpg">
            <p>High speed meets high stakes in Need for Speed: Rivals. Play as a lone-wolf racer or a team-based cop as you speed... </p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://images.pushsquare.com/games/ps4/watch_dogs/cover_large.jpg">
            <p>Join the Community and Social Team from GAME as they head to Paris for a special Watch Dogs event with Ubisoft!.. </p>
        </td>    
        <td>
            <img src="http://images.pushsquare.com/games/ps3/last_of_us/cover_large.jpg">
            <p>From the creators of the Uncharted Series comes an emotionally-charged experience that’ll keep you gripped...</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table> 
</div>
</div>
<!--End Of Tables-->

<!--Start of chart-->
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="table-chart">
<table class="background">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3"><h1>Game Charts</h1></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h1>1</h1></td>
        <td><img src="http://images.pushsquare.com/games/ps3/gran_turismo_6/cover_large.jpg"</td>
        <td><h3>Gran Turismo</h3><a href="#" class="view-review">View Review</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h1>2</h1></td>
        <td><img src="http://images.pushsquare.com/games/ps3/call_of_duty_ghosts/cover_large.jpg"</td>
        <td><h3>Call of Duty:Ghosts</h3><a href="#" class="view-review">View Review</a>      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h1>3</h1></td>
        <td><img src="http://images.pushsquare.com/games/ps4/killzone_shadow_fall/cover_large.jpg"</td>
        <td><h3>Killzone</h3><a href="#" class="view-review">View Review</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--End of chart-->
</div>
<div class="feature-article">
<div ="feature-back">
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Call Of Duty: Ghosts</h2>
            <img src="http://eaglerising.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/call_of_duty_ghosts-hd-300x180.jpg">
            <p>Build your team and take up to 6 of them into battle in the all new Squads mode. This mode takes the best parts of the multiplayer experience and allows you to play either solo or cooperatively with the custom soldiers created and leveled up in multiplaye</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div id="feature_back">
            <h2>Grand Theft Auto V</h2>
            <img src="http://ronewiznation.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/grand-theft-auto-game-cover.jpg?w=300&h=180">
            <p>Grand Theft Auto V Los Santos: a sprawling sun-soaked metropolis full of self-help gurus, starlets, and fading celebrities, once the envy of the Western world, now struggling to stay afloat in an era of economic uncertainty and cheap reality TV. </p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Assasins Creed</h2>
            <img src="http://www.ketubanjiwa.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Assassins-Creed-IV-Black-Flag-Freedom-Cry-DLC-Reloaded-Single-Link-300x180.jpg">
            <p>The year is 1715. Pirates rule the Caribbean and have established their own lawless Republic where corruption, greediness and cruelty are commonplace.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background-color:#121212;
}
.bodytwo {
background-color:white;
position:relative;
}
.nav {
background-color:black;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
z-index:5;
}
.nav li {
display:inline;
}
.nav a {
padding:10px 8px;
position:relative;
top:6px;
color:#FF6600;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
#logo-game img {
position:relative;
height:50px;
left:20%;
}
.jumbotron {
position:relative;
top:50px;
background-image:url('http://collectortoys.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/battlefield-4-server-bannerladder-standings-for-xboxone-battlefield-4---bf4-xbox-one-mretosqa.jpg');
height:500px;
z-index:2;
background-size:cover;
}
.feature-cont {
position:relative;
left:800px;
width:350px;
color:white;
z-index:2;
}
#feature-cont-back {
background-color:rgba(20,20,20,.5);
width:400px;
height:400px;
position:relative;
border-radius:10px;
padding:5px;
z-index:1;
}
.jumbotron h1 {
font-family:ubuntu, Arial;
}
.recommended li {
display:inline;
margin:auto;
float: none;
position:relative;
top:80px;
}
.new-game {
position:relative;
}
.new-game td, th {
padding: 0.5;
}
.new-game table {
border-collapse:separate;
border-spacing:15px 10px;
border: 1px solid black;
border-top-left-radius:10px;
border-top-right-radius:10px;
border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
}
.new-game tr {
padding:10px;

}
.new-game tr th {
text-align:center;
color:white;
font-family:ubuntu;
font-size:25px;
}
.new-game td {
padding:10px;
width:100px;
height:200px;
vertical-align:top;
background-color: rgba(24,24,24,.2);
border-top-left-radius:10px;
border-top-right-radius:10px;
border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
border-bottom-right-radius:10px;

}
.new-game td p {
text-align:center;
font-family:arial;
font-size:12px;
color:white;
}
.new-game td img {
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
.background { 
background: url("http://i1057.photobucket.com/albums/t390/Alexwileyy/box-01_zpsdd34bf84.png") 
no-repeat;
height:500px;
width:424px;

}
.table-chart table {
position:relative;
border-collapse:separate;
}
.table-chart tr td h3 {
width:150px;
text-align: center;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:20px;
position:relative;
top:-20px;
color:black;
}
.table-chart td a {
position:relative;
top:-20px;
}
.table-chart td img {
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
.table-chart th h1 {
text-align:center;
font-family:ubuntu;
color: #dd6a15;
text-shadow: 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
.table-chart td {
padding:15px;
box-shadow: 0 3px 1px rgba(26,26,26,0.75);
}
.feature-article {
position:relative;
clear:both;
height:400px;
border-bottom:3px solid #2f2f2f;
border-top:3px solid #2f2f2f;
background-image:url('http://i1057.photobucket.com/albums/t390/Alexwileyy/1_zps87c3163e.jpg');

}
.feature-article .col-md-4 {
width:370px;
height:200px;
text-align:center;
margin:auto;
z-index:1;
}
.feature-article .col-md-4 img {
width:300px;
height:180px;
}
.feature-article .col-md-4 p {
width:350px;
}
#feature_back {
clear:both;
background-image:url('http://i1057.photobucket.com/albums/t390/Alexwileyy/line-01_zps79e6ad19.png');
height:400px;
width:370px;
padding-left:10px;
background-repeat:no-repeat
}
/*Buttons Design*/
.view-review {
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
padding: 14px 26px;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 100%;
text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
color: #fff;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
font-weight: bold;
transition: background 0.1s ease-in-out;
/*for different browsers */
-webkit-transition: background 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: background 0.1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: background 0.1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: background 0.1s ease-in-out;
/*END*/
text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
color: #fff;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.view-review:active {
padding-top: 15px;
margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.view-review, .view-review:hover, .view-review:active {
outline: 0 none;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
border-radius: 3px;
}

.view-review {
background-color: #2f2f2f;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #ea6300;
width:150px;
height:35px;
}
.view-review:hover {
background-color: #454545;
}
.mainc .row {
position:relative;
top:80px;
}
```

To summarise I want to have the white background wrapped around only the table elements on the page running all the way down the page, however the bottom element is overlapping the tables.
Any idea at all of what I could possible do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you gave a 'top:80' to '.mainc .row'. This causes the overlap. Delete it, and your footer will not overlap the content. Also, give a 'margin-top:100px' to your '.mainc' class. this will fix the new overlapping problem.

You need to learn to use bootstrap more efficiently. Don't be afraid to abuse bootstrap's 'container' and 'row' divs. Think of those element as some big lego blocs that will stack themselves untop of each others.

Also I would not recommend using tables, as they are old-school and less edit-friendly. Use DIVs, you will have more control over them and they will adjust more easily with bootstrap.

If you want your site to be responsive, learn how to scale and place your columns accordingly by adding all of bootstrap 'col-x-x' classes.

Comment: Thank you very much, only just started coding and it all confuses me the laying out, especially bootstrap. Not to sure how to figure it all out but I am sure I'll get there eventually

Comment: Glad I could be of help! And don't worry, practice makes perfect, as in most things. Keep at it and you'll get better. I totally understand you. If you ever have a bit of free time, don't hesitate to check [bootstrap's own documentation (CSS, Components and Javascript)](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) and experiment. A nifty trick I find useful is adding a background color to all my DIVs when i'm building a layout. This way you can see if they are stacked correctly, have the desired width, etc. This site is also useful [CSS-Tricks] (http://css-tricks.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You're adding `position:relative` all over for no good reason. In general you use `position:relative` to set the anchor point for absolutely-positioned child elements. You'd then use `position:absolute` to move those elements around in the layout.

If you need to perform minor tweaks of element positioning, use `margin:`, not `position:relative`.